# Silverlight Navigation , Get rid of '#'

Tags: navigation, silverlight-4.0

I am trying to create a silverlght navigation application and it is adding this "#" sign by default in the URL. I want to use asp .net routing and somehow get rid of this "#" sign. Is this possible ? How ? Any sample or right direction will be really helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Silverlight navigation uses the bookmark anchor feature to stay on the same host page.

Without the "#" your host page would be reloaded and you would lose all of your in-memory application state.

Use of asp.net routing would be distinct from using Silverlight navigation.

Comment: So if I understood well, getting rid of # is almost impossible?

Comment: Yes. I think that the # is essential for Silverlight navigation.